# how to automatically add org-emphasis properties to list titles?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, list, org-emphasis

I use org-mode lists, both plain-text lists and numbered lists. I precede my lists with a "list title," which for me is any line ending in a colon.

```
Grocery list:
- tomatoes
- spinach
- blueberries
```

I'd like these list titles to be automatically italicized in export to HTML and LaTeX PDF.

I don't want to do this by making it a headline, since [by design](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2010-11/msg01293.html), as we know, [there is no way to end an org-heading and return to the parent level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793428/how-to-end-todo-lists-in-emacs-org-mode) without creating a new heading.

So instead, I want org to automatically consider any lines ending with a colon as list titles. (Even better would be to exclude headlines and lines that have a period somewhere before the ending colon.)

I figured out how to fontify such lines within the Emacs buffer itself by defining a new face:

```
(defface list-title-face
'((t (:background "pale green")))
"fontify list titles")

 (font-lock-add-keywords 'org-mode
'(("^.*:[ ]*$" . 'list-title-face)))
```

But how do I create an org-emphasis type so that the emphasis will be respected in org-export?

UPDATE: `org-emphasis-regexp-components` looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Org provides a variety of hooks to modify text on export.  So, re-using your regular expression and org's italic emphasis, one way would be

```
(add-hook 'org-export-before-parsing-hook (lambda (backend)
            (replace-regexp "^\\(.*:\\)[ ]*$" "/\\1/")))
```

Of course, then it will only appear in the exported document.  So you may want to define a custom face and add a hook for the export.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to define an `org-emphasis` type? What about using `org-emphasis-regexp-components`?

Comment: Org emphasis types require a character to mark the start and end, as far as I know, it won't match an arbitrary regex.

Comment: This seems like a promising approach. However, it creates some unintended consequences. Here's an [example](http://incandescentman.github.io/stackexchange/example.html). (The last line should not appear, however it does appear and is converted to italics.) Source is here: http://incandescentman.github.io/stackexchange/example.org

Comment: I guess it needs a way to distinguish between list titles and org-mode tags.